# GDCM python DICOM decompression

Tags: python, swig, dicom, gdcm

I executed this [python script](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/DecompressImage_8py-example.html). An error happened in the line

```
t = gdcm.Orientation.GetType(dircos)
```

The error information is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2820, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-8-fb43b0929780>", line 1, in <module>
    gdcm.Orientation.GetType(dircos)
TypeError: expected a list.
```

I looked up the [classes reference](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/classgdcm_1_1Orientation.html). It says

> Input is an array of 6 double

The variable `dircos` is exactly a list with 6 elements,

```
>>> dircos
Out[11]: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```

I don't know why it goes wrong.

Comment: This has been reported as a bug upstream in [swig](https://sourceforge.net/p/swig/bugs/1382/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the source code and found that it actually check for `tuple`. The message is misleading.

```c
// Grab a 6 element array as a Python 6-tuple
%typemap(in) const double dircos[6] (double temp[6]) {   // temp[6] becomes a local variable
  int i;
  if (PyTuple_Check($input) /*|| PyList_Check($input)*/) {
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple($input,"dddddd",temp,temp+1,temp+2,temp+3,temp+4,temp+5)) {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"list must have 6 elements");
      return NULL;
    }
    $1 = &temp[0];
  } else {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"expected a list.");
    return NULL;
  }
}
```

You need to pass a tuple:

```
>>> import gdcm
>>> dircos = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
>>> gdcm.Orientation.GetType(tuple(dircos))
1
```